# How can I get Javascript to execute as a table is being built?

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic, vbscript

I have a table being built in HTML (using ASP), and it's stepping through a recordset.  As it steps through the recordset, it creates a new row for the html table and fills it with data.

The problem I'm having is that it's using numbers that can be 10 or 11 digits long, and I want to format it with commas.  I have a formatNumbers function that works excellently.  However, basically what I need to do is this:

`<td><script>formatNumber(<% = RS("total_rolled_lineal_ft")%>,0,0,true);</script></td>`

I'm getting an Object Expected error.  If we take a line from the executed HTML, here's what it looks like:
`<td><script>formatNumber(10843537,0,0,true);</script></td>`

Any clue what's causing my error, or, if I'm doing it completely wrong, how to fix it?

Also, formatNumber returns a string, in this case `10,843,537`.

Comment: Please show the `formatNumber()` declaration. Why don't you use a server-side number formatting routine?

Comment: I'm actually not sure how to do that. What would I use?  Also, I'm using vbscript.  I forgot to say that in the OP

Comment: Well [`FormatNumber()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfta99yt(v=vs.80).aspx) is the first VB number formatting function I found with Google. As far as your "Object Expected" error, you'll have to show your function declaration for further help. Though if the function returns a string as you mention then you'd probably need `<script>document.write(formatNumber(...))</script>` so that the string is actually output to the page.

Comment: Wow, oh my goodness.  It does exist.  I got it working using FormatNumber().  Thanks so much for the suggestion.  I feel really dumb that I didn't even think about using VB.  I just assumed it had to be done using javascript.

Comment: If you'll submit what I put as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @nnnnnn, I ended up using VB's FormatNumber() and came up with this

`<% = FormatNumber(RS("total_rolled_lineal_ft"),0,true,true,true)%>`, which works excellently.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used straight ASP so maybe I am missing something in this answer.

Technically you can not execute Javascript while the ui is rendering, browsers tend to be a single threaded affair and will do one thing or the other.

But I would suggest that instead of binding the table directly to a record set you transform the record set into a ViewModel type class in the code behind.

You would then perform this conversion as you are building your ViewModel.